# Openshift oc new-app how to maps secrets of another pod?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

I have a project/namespace in Openshift 3.9. It has one Mysql db pod, the credentials details are stored as `secrets`.

[image]

While deploying my Springboot application, in Openshift UI, I change the `Deployment Configuration` to map the dynamic variables from my APP to Mysql secrets.

[image]

Now I want to automate this step, and how do I mention/pass these secrets while using the `oc new-app` cmd. I am using below command, but not sure on how to pass/map variables to secrets.

```
oc new-app redhat-openjdk18-openshift~https://github.com/xyzasdkjasnda/openshift-mysql
```

Somewhere I saw a workaround like below,

> oc new-app
>   redhat-openjdk18-openshift~https://github.com/xyzasdkjasnda/openshift-mysql
>   | jq '.items[] | select(.kind == "DeploymentConfig") |
>   .spec.template.spec.containers[0].env +=
>   [{"name":"db_name","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"database-name","name":"mysql"}}},{"name":"db_username","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"database-user","name":"mysql"}}},{"name":"db_password","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"database-password","name":"mysql"}}}]'
>   | \
>       oc apply --filename -

Answer (score 0):

While `oc new-app` seems convenient, it usually is preferred to explicitly create a [DeploymentConfig](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/deployments/how_deployments_work.html#creating-a-deployment-configuration) (or Deployment) file and check it into a code repo; use `oc create -f <deployment-filename>` to create the actual object in OpenShift.

See [Example #3 here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/secrets.html#secrets-examples) for how to populate environment variables with values from Secrets - that is what the "workaround" does.

Alternatively, you can still use `oc new-app` to create a new application, including [building it from source code](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/new_app.html#specifying-source-code), which will create the DeploymentConfig you can then [edit](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#edit) to add the environment variables from Secrets configuration.

Comment: Ok, let's say I am using a `dc.json` for deployment config, and I have added few variables like `${APP_NAME}` in `dc.json`. How do we pass these variable in `oc create -f dc.json`

Comment: I have used the following approach: define env vars with the values to be replaced (e.g. `export APP_NAME=my-app`); pre-process the yaml file (json could work, too) that has the placeholders (e.g. `${APP_NAME}`) by `grep`-ing for what is in between `${` and `}` delimiters and `eval`-uating it as an environment variable; search-n-replace via `sed` the placeholders with the evaluated env var value; pass the result to `oc apply`. (Sorry, it probably sounds cryptic). Some solutions like [helm](https://github.com/helm/helm) allow similar use and substitution of placeholder values and more.